# Github API get Comments made in a file

Tags: github, github-api

Reading through the documentation of gh api v3 , I wasn't able to find an endpoint the would return to me the comments made in a line. Is it possible to get the comments made so they can be deleted or edited ?

Comment: What does "comments made into line" mean? Are you talking about pull request comments?

Comment: What I mean is when you set a comment in a line making a suggestion

Comment: On a pull request?

Comment: Yes on PR, I know there is a end point for getting the comments on PR but those don't bring the comments some one does on a file line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get pull request review comments, you can use [Github API v3 list review comments on pull request](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/comments/#list-comments-on-a-pull-request):

```
GET /repos/:owner/:repo/pulls/:number/comments
```

For example : https://api.github.com/repos/mui-org/material-ui/pulls/3132/comments

To edit/delete a review comment, get the review comment ID and then use [edit review comment API](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/comments/#edit-a-comment) and [delete review comment API](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/comments/#delete-a-comment)